# Do older raspberry pi accessories (specifically cameras) become obsoleted and experience reduced-price sales to the public?

Tags: camera, peripherals, purchasing

I have an older Pi B with 512MB of RAM. I'm considering volunteering to help a local publicly funded park with a raspberry pi nature camera project, but I anticipate no funding from them, at least to start. This being the case, I've been looking at the variety of camera/imaging modules and hoping to find some older, perhaps obsolete modules on closeout or at reduced cost, but I have yet to find any obvious candidates.

Recalling previous releases of new boards, the rapid selling-out of the newer boards, and then gradual selling-off of older boards, I'm not sure that I could expect any stock to remain of older camera modules, or even if there *are* any older camera modules. With this in mind, can anyone reference an older camera module that is available on closeout/clearance/discount to the public, or cite an example when this has happened in the past (perhaps after a new hardware release)?

Comment: I highly doubt that raspberry pi cameras experience reduced/clearance pricing. As their appears to be a relatively high demand for them and they aren't something that goes out of date rapidly like cell phones

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [shopping recommendation request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad).